# Binary tree code error

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a code to insert elements into a binary tree without recursion.But the problem i am facing is that each time i try to insert a node,it doesnot get inserted and the tree does not grow as expected.Only the first element remains in the tree.

```
void insert(struct node **head1,int data1)
{
    struct node *temp1,*temp;

    temp=*head1;
    struct node *datatemp,*prevtemp;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data < data1)
        {
            temp=temp->right;
        }
        else if(temp->data > data1)
        {
            temp=temp->left;
        }
    }
    datatemp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    datatemp->data=data1;
    datatemp->right=NULL;
    datatemp->left=NULL;
    temp=datatemp;
}
```

Please help..i have tried to debug but i cant find the error in my logic.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your tag from c++ to c since you apparently use the C language. Also, please read this: [mcve].

Comment: What do you think this `temp=datatemp;` is supposed to do?

Comment: make sure you handle the case where the second number you're trying to insert is same as the first number. Your code handles < & > but not ==

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to specify `struct` when supplying the type name to the function.  This is a difference between C++ and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here `temp=datatemp;` sets the local pointer in your function to point to the newly allocated node.
But once the functions exists, that local is gone, and your memory leaks. You don't modify the node you found.